Replacing one sheet with CSV in the current directory
I have a Data.ods file in  which there is a sheet name stocks.I need to change this sheet frequently with another csv file in the current directory .I need to write a macro in Libre Office which asks user to pick the csv file and replace the sheet named stock with the picked .csv file. Can someone give a macro for this in Libre office? Thanks for the help.
I read the documentation but couldn't figure out ,I got stuck on how to write a amcro such that it pick file from curr directory. If someone give me a sample macro to do that that would be helpful . Thanks
Sub OpenFileWithFileDialog()
    Dim oFileDialog As Object
    Dim sSelectedFile As String

    ' Create a file dialog
    oFileDialog = CreateUnoService("com.sun.star.ui.dialogs.FilePicker")

    ' Set properties of the file dialog
    oFileDialog.Title = "Select File to Open"
  

    ' Set the type of dialog to open
    oFileDialog.appendFilter("All Files (*.*)", "*.*")

    ' Show the dialog and get the selected file
    If oFileDialog.execute() = com.sun.star.ui.dialogs.ExecutableDialogResults.OK Then
        sSelectedFile = oFileDialog.Files(0)
        
        ' Open the selected file in Calc
        If FileExists(sSelectedFile) Then
            Dim oDoc As Object
            oDoc = StarDesktop.loadComponentFromURL(ConvertToURL(sSelectedFile), "_blank", 0, Array())
        Else
            MsgBox "File not found: " & sSelectedFile, 48, "Error"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
Function FileExists(sPath As String) As Boolean
    FileExists = Dir(sPath) <> ""
End Function



The error is

Invalid use of object showing in the line oFileDialog.Files(0).


"Can someone give a macro for this in Libre office?" This is not a code writing service. However, you asked about a specific error, so I answered that.

This question is about LibreOffice Basic, not Microsoft VBA, so please change the tags.

It sounds like you're having trouble getting FilePicker working. To find the problem, do things one step at a time.
iAccept = oFileDialog.Execute()
If iAccept = com.sun.star.ui.dialogs.ExecutableDialogResults.OK Then
    If Ubound(oFileDialog.Files) < 0 Then 
        sFileName = ""
    Else 
        sFileName = oFileDialog.Files(0)
    End If
    MsgBox sFileName
End If

There's also a related question about multiple files: LibreOffice how to get filepicker multiple file selection data
